PPI-SF - Psychopathic personality inventory - Short form
We are hoping to do a short research project using the PPI-SF as developed and validated by Toner et al., 2012 (DOI 10.1007/s10862-012-9333-2) but I cannot find an accessible version of it anywhere. Can anyone direct me to where I might find it?
Edit: specifically, I wish to access the so-called PPI-Revised-SF. The authors of the linked study say they accessed it from Psychological Assessment Resources - but the revised short version doesn't come up when I search there?

You can always contact the (corresponding) author(s) of the papers you cite.
In the meantime, the following link of ArabPsychology seems to feature the questionnaire you are after. I don't know whether the source can be trusted, but it looks legit.

Thanks AliceD - I found the ArabPsyc one but it has less items that it should do so I'm not sure it's legit. I think I will contact a few authors.
